# AngularJS: Update template binding via directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I modified the AngularUI-Bootstrap direvtive for tooltips to help me display error messages, here is what I did so far: http://jsfiddle.net/distractedBySquirrels/TaAHZ/

But I have a problem with the dynamic messages. The first time you mouseover the first input field, the message is in the wrong place, this is because the model is not correctly updated yet. Of course, after the second mouseover the tooltip is in the right place. But if the message to display changes again the same failure occurs.

I am using `$parse` to update the template:

```
$parse('tt_content').assign( scope, 
    getErrorMessage( ctrl.$error ) || attrs.tooltip
);
```

Seems like not all the listeners have revceived and updated and "ttHeight" and "ttWidth" are still set to the "old" values. The correct update of the message/model only works with the $observe, which is illustrated by the third example.

I am stuck and don't know what I did wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you modify your models with $apply, you need to ***manually*** activate the digest cycle in order to notify all watchers of such models. So basically, you need to add `scope.$digest();` whenever you change the scope doing things like `scope.$apply( show );`

I modified your code with my suggestions here http://jsfiddle.net/TaAHZ/2/

Comment: `$apply` causes Angular to enter its [digest loop](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime).  "The $digest loop keeps iterating until the model stabilizes."  You do not need to call `$digest` as well -- that would just cause Angular to enter its digest loop again.  Your fiddle does not appear to fix the problem.

Comment: How comes the problem is not solved in  http://jsfiddle.net/TaAHZ/2/ ?  It looks fine to me (assuming the delay is a desired behavior, see JS line 109).

I believe that calling manually $digest, even after $apply, solves this issue.

Comment: I tried it in Chrome, and the tooltip for the first input field still appears in the wrong place initially with your fiddle.  If I mouse-over the field, the tooltip is in the wrong place.  If I mouse-over again, it then appears in the correct place, just like the OP's fiddle.

Comment: I was not aware of the positioning issues. I actually do not understand what's the desired behavior to position the tooltips. I focused on making work the show/hide functionality

Comment: I updated the fiddle, maybe this helps why the repositioning has to work: http://jsfiddle.net/distractedBySquirrels/TaAHZ/4/ 
I also added some console output to illustrate the problem. The message is updated but the view isn't.

Comment: Here is another update where it is working, but cheated...
http://jsfiddle.net/distractedBySquirrels/TaAHZ/5/